# How the lbu MIPS instruction works

Tags: mips

Quick question involving a problem on my review for class:

`lbu $R2, 24($R2)`

So the problem wants us to show the value of register $R2 after the above instruction is executed.

Two things are given (all values are in decimal):

`$R2 = 12`

And the memory addresses:
`36 = -18, 32 = 99, 28 = 177, 24 = -14`

I'm just a little lost on how exactly the `lbu` instruction works. I'm pretty sure that the instruction is going to load the right most byte based on the offset provided into $R2 and not sign extend it but what exactly does this mean? I have a few answers in mind, just not entirely sure.

As well as how would this same instruction behave if the instruction was just `lb` vs `lbu`

Answer (score 1):

> and not sign extend it but what exactly does this mean?

Sign-extension: The remaining bits of the word are all set to the value of the most significant bit of the loaded entity.

For example: 0x80 => 0xFFFFFF80, and 0x7F => 0x0000007F.

---

Zero-extension: The remaining bits of the word are all set to zero.

For example: 0x80 => 0x00000080, and 0x7F => 0x0000007F.

---

In your example, the byte at `24($R2)` is -18 (0xEE), assuming a little-endian layout. This would be 0xFFFFFFEE when sign-extended, and 0x000000EE when zero-extended.